# MATH how to rotate vertices by using cos and sin

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangular specified by the follow four vertices.

```
    x y h
    6 1 1
X = 8 1 1
    8 5 1
    6 5 1
```

And I have to rotate this triangle about he origin of the coordinate system by 30 degrees. Assuming the following is the formula used to rotate the four vertices.

```
     cos0   sin0  0
 R = -sin0  cos0  0
     0      0     1
```

So to rotate by 30 degree do I just go multiple X with R and replacing the cos0 with cos30, sin0 with sin30, and so on?

Like this?

$6*cos30 + 1*(-sin30) + 1*0$

$6*sin30 + 1*cos30 + 1*0$

$6*0 + 1*0 + 1*1$

$8*cos30 + 1*(-sin30) + 1*0$

$8*sin30 + 1*cos30 + 1*0$

$8*0 + 1*0 + 1*1$

$8*cos30 + 5*(-sin30) + 1*0$

$8*sin30 + 5*cos30 + 1*0$

$8*0 + 1*0 + 1*1$

$6*cos30 + 5*(-sin30) + 1*0$

$6*sin30 + 5*cos30 + 1*0$

$6*0 + 5*0 + 1*1$

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little further, you can put all your xyz coordinates in the right hand matrix: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta &\sin \theta  &0 \\ 
-\sin \theta&\cos \theta  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4
\\y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4
\\h_1 & h_2 & h_3 & h_4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta &\sin \theta  &0 \\ 
-\sin \theta&\cos \theta  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x
\\y 
\\h
\end{pmatrix}$ And then multiply them together using matrix multiplication. For example $x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta+0*h$ for the first row

Comment: this is exactly what i was doing, but it doesn't seem like the rectangle rotated 30 degree nor does it seem like the new vertices even represents a rectangle.